# Does libgit2 supports redirect all operations to .git directory?

Tags: libgit2

This [article](http://blog.deveo.com/your-git-repository-in-a-database-pluggable-backends-in-libgit2/) mentioned to redirect objects and refs folder to database, can other files under git repo (`.git` folder) be redirected in similar way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libgit2 allows you to replace the default accessors so you don't have to store data in the git-dir, but it does not provide a way to avoid having the git-dir.

The git-dir is where Git stores data about the state of the repository, which includes references, a configuration file and the objects. These are three things which you can ask libgit2 to use a different object instead of the one which does look at the directory as git creates them. This can make those repositories not be compatible with git itself, so it's not a decision to be taken lightly.

But the git-dir also contains an excludes file, the index, hooks, `MERGE_HEAD` and the other `_HEAD` files, the temporary files for the commit's message, the rebase's instruction sheet... None of these things are full-blown objects which libgit2 lets you plug in, some of them aren't read by libgit2 at all either.